# Why does Android Studio suggest to replace for loop with foreach loop?

Tags: java, android

I write this simple for loop in Android Studio.

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
    myTextView.append(arrayList[i] + "\n\n\n");
}
```

But it suggests to change this for loop with the foreach loop. Like this

```
for (String arrayLists : arrayList) {
    myTextView.append(arrayList + "\n\n\n");
}
```

Why does Android Studio suggest foreach loop rather than for loop? Are there any benefit using foreach loop rather than for loop?

Comment: In this specific case, it's more compact and less error prone (since you don't need to manage `i`). You wouldn't believe how many questions we get here with nested loops where the inner loop uses the outer index by mistake.

Comment: It's incrementally more concise and it's more generic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually sometimes benefits with a for each loop, due to the fact of it using an iterator as opposed to accessing elements by index. This can be a lot faster in some cases, a `LinkedList` comes to mind as being an obvious example. This same benefit won't apply if you're using an `ArrayList` though.

Having said that, I would actually expect the warning is simply due to writing concise code and not necessarily for performance reasons.